# Check of URL Parameters are set

Tags: apex

I was wondering if people knew how to check if a URL parameter is set?

For instance, I have an application that may or may not have a query attached to the URL. Something like this:

> ...salesforce.com/apex/project?id=##################

I understand to grab that ID in Apex it would look something like:

```
public String id = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
```

What I want to do is check if that's been set.

In PHP, I know you can check for things like this:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // Do something...
  }
?>
```

I'm just looking for the Apex equivilant.

Hope I've been clear enough,

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly it should simply be a case of:

```
    public String idParam = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');

    if (idParam != null) {
      doSomething();
    }
```

You could also go a step further and check that it is an actual Id, not some other value such as a string:

```
if (idParam != null && idParam instanceOf Id)
```

I think Id is a reserved keyword in Apex so I've changed your param to 'idParam'.

Comment: This place would be more helpful if the people downvoting my answer commented on why my answer is wrong.

Comment: The `id` parameter shouldn't be retrieved this way; Salesforce make no assertions about its presence, and it even disappears out of the URL when viewstate is reloaded. Any other param OK!

Comment: The OPs question was simply how to check if the parameter was set - I see what you're saying but it was a simple question with a simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am checking it this way:

1. key exists check
2. key is not null

Example:

```
if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().containsKey('param1') && ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('param1') != '')
{
....
}
```